# Reformatting dataset by column value

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, macros

I have a question regarding the reformatting of a large subset of data in Excel. As it currently stands, the data is in four columns, sorted by the "Block" values as follows.

[image]

What I'd like is to create a function (or perhaps macro) that can sort through the data and take all the data corresponding to "Block" values of 2, cut those values out, and paste them next to the "F635 Mean" values corresponding to Block 1. I want to iterate that process for Block 3 as well, and any other Block values that may exist. The result should look like this:

[image]

Of course, I did that manually but it's tedious when the Block numbers extend to 20+. I've tried to create a macro to do this, but can't seem to get it to work (and didn't save it, otherwise I'd post my code...sorry).

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your "block" values are already in order, as they appear in your example, then I think this will work:

```
Sub FunnySort()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim row, lastRow, newRow, newCol, block, oldBlock As Integer
  Dim fromCell, toCell As Range

  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
  lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  oldBlock = ws.Range("B2").Value2
  newCol = 1

  For row = 3 To lastRow
    block = ws.Cells(row, 2).Value2

    If block = oldBlock And newCol = 1 Then
      ' same initial block -- don't do anything
    Else
      If block <> oldBlock Then
        newRow = 2
        newCol = newCol + 5
        oldBlock = block
      End If

      Set fromCell = ws.Cells(newRow, newCol)
      Set toCell = ws.Cells(newRow, newCol + 4)

      ws.Range(fromCell, toCell).Value2 = ws.Range("A" & row & ":E" & row).Value2
      newRow = newRow + 1
      ws.Range("A" & row & ":E" & row).Clear
    End If
  Next row
End Sub
```

If it's not in order, that's easy enough to add.

Also, this presupposes that if your "block" value skips numbers (ie goes from 3 to 5), it doesn't also skip a block of columns, it will just take the next available.  From your example, I couldn't tell what behavior you wanted.  If you want to skip, that's easy enough to incorporate as well.